# django mod wsgi apache2 configuration

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm using apache2.4 on ubuntu 14.04, I started new project from django documentation, then I checked that app runs using python runserver, it works great, but in my server apache2 i see 500 error. My config:
/etc/apache2/sites-available/django.td.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName  django.td
#DocumentRoot /
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/s/py/django/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
Alias /adminmedia/  /opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
<Directory "/home/s/py/django/mysite/mysite/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and lastest logs:

```
[Mon Jun 16 17:11:27.892188 2014] [:error] [pid 4054] [client 127.0.0.1:59541] ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named mysite.settings
```

Comment: Can you post the wsgi.py file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have 'mysite' added to the python path in your wsgi.py.

Comment: I have the same problem! Could you tell me how you solve that?